# help with breaking down this sentence: 私が今まで見た中で最も面白いもの

Tags: grammar, particles

> 私が今まで見た中で最も面白いもの

I (think?) understand the meaning of the sentence but I have a hard time understanding the grammar.
My two questions are:

- What is the role of the で In mid sentence? I’ve been told that で  particle can be used to specify the context to a verb which means it can only be used when there’s a verb in the sentence and I don’t see a verb here. The only other で That I know of is the transformed version of だ for compound sentences which I don’t think would make much sense here?
- Why use 私が Instead of 私は? Is there a specific reason/ what would it imply otherwise? I’m still new to particles so I have a hard time telling apart the exact conditions for using either of the two, so this might help me understand a bit more. (I do know the basics of the differences between が and は)

I found this somewhere on Twitter so it might not be abide by the grammar rules and if so I would like to see how it should be said in a way that’s grammatically correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly grammatical and perfectly natural noun phrase. It means "the funniest thing I've ever seen", or a bit more literally, "the funniest thing among the things which I have ever seen".

> What is the role of the で In mid sentence?

As you say, で can mark various kinds of *context* (or *scope*, *situation*, *condition*). Examples include 合計で ("in total"), 1人で ("alone"), 家族で ("with one's family"), 最高で ("at most"), 仮定で ("hypothetically"), その上で ("taking this into consideration"), この村で ("in this village"), and so on. Since this で forms an adverbial expression, some can also modify an adjective.

- この村で最も強い戦士 the strongest warrior in this village
- 1人でも楽しい fun even when you're alone
- その上で高い expensive (even) after taking it into consideration

中で is an example of this.

> Why use 私が Instead of 私は?

Have you already learned [relative clauses](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-relative-clauses/)? This 中 is technically a noun, and 私が今まで見た is a relative clause that modifies 中. Inside a relative clause, you basically cannot use は.