# What is the role of で in the following sentence?

Tags: particle-で

The following is a sentence from a reading comprehension exercise. The context is a 返品カード. I wonder what role で plays below:

> 返品理由**で**当てはまるものを選び、アルファベットに◯をつけてください。
>
> a．サイズが合わなかった。
>
> b. ...

I have two guesses.

1. で here is the te-form of だ. 返品理由 and 当てはまる both modify もの.
2. で is a particle and means “as”.

Which (if any) of the above would be correct?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/78810/5010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can read the sentence as 返品理由**の中で**当てはまる… so で plays
"location" role (**inside the** list, choose corresponding...).